# Gmail Calendar event integration into Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I know the way to sent email event remainder with Google calendar. I also know it is possible to publish the link to event with a link, but I want to create a calendar email invite that shows in my outbox and also pushes a notification of event in the calendar app of receiver as an event.